# E: Unable to locate package usbmount

Tags: docker, apt-get, debian-stretch

I've installed a debian stretch container in docker (via portainer.io) 
and was able to install openssh-server via apt-get install.

After a successful connection with PuTTY, i'm not able to install usbmount which i need for later purpose..

i searched a lot and went through different repositories but nothing helped - i'm getting the same error every time.

of course, i **typed in apt-get update after every edit of sources.list**

by looking for another solution i've tried to install apt-file and for some reason this works, but usbmount wont...

this is the content of my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

any suggestions?
thanks in advance

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=usbmount
is it not aviable for stretch?